# difficulty translating C# code into jquery datepicker logic

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

First off, thanks for taking the time to help out.

I have the following code server-side:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                dateFrom.Date = dateTo.Date.AddMonths(-1);
                dateFrom.MinDate = dateTo.Date.AddMonths(-6);
                dateFrom.MaxDate = dateTo.Date;
                dateTo.Date = DateTime.Now;
                dateTo.MinDate = dateFrom.Date;
                dateTo.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
```

...

So when the page loads, I'd like to set the current date of the dateFrom datepicker to today's date minus 1 month and the minimum date to -6 months from today.

Furthermore I have the following code:

```
   protected void dateFrom_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTo.MinDate = dateFrom.Date;
    }

    protected void dateTo_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateFrom.MinDate = dateTo.Date.AddMonths(-6);
        dateFrom.MaxDate = dateTo.Date;
    }
```

which states that when a date is selected from the dateFrom calendar I want to set the min date of the DateTo callendar to the date of the DateFrom calendar.

Any help or directions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I figured that I have to work with the 'onSelect' event of jquery Datepicker, but I don't know if I should use it when i initialize the datepicker of use the 'option' API.

Thank you heaps!

Answer (score 1):

See jQuery UI's [Date Range sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range), which does exactly what you're looking for.

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

You would also want to set `minDate: "-6M"` for  the from picker.

Comment: Why? What don't you understand?

Comment: I understand 60% of the code. I undestand that I select the option 'MinDate' or 'MaxDate' etc.. WHat I don't understand from this code is where to set the business rules like stated above in my question?

Comment: I just don't see how this works.. Im sorry. I'll google around for answers. THanks for your time. I upvoted your answer for your effort